# Apache2.4.27 could not find ssl_module in mod_ssl.so

Tags: apache, ssl

I am trying to setup a local https server using Apache2.4.27.
I have followed the instruction given on this website [how to setup SSL on Apache](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-ssl).

When I uncomment `LoadModule ssl_module libexec/mod_ssl.so` on my Apache httpd configuration, I got the following error when I tried to restart my Apache server:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 141 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `ssl_module' in file /usr/local/opt/httpd24/libexec/mod_ssl.so: dlsym(0x7fe0a1c07080, ssl_module): symbol not found
```

I have confirmed that there is mod_ssl.so file inside my httpd's libexec folder.

I wonder where did I go wrong, since fresh installation of openssl and apache could not help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you considered following the *Apache HTTPD* documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have tried following apache httpd documentation on how to configure SSL/TLS encryption (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).

But it still gives me the same syntax error.
If I comment the `LoadModule ssl_module libexec/mod_ssl.so`, the server would work fine. However, I could not use the https in my local environment.

Comment: The Apache HTTPD mod_ssl document you just cited says `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes, I have tried that too. When I changed to `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`, it returned error that the file is not found.

I have finally solve this problem. it seems that there is some problem with the mod_ssl.so file included in the apache installation via homebrew.

I replaced the original mod_ssl.so file with another mod_ssl.so from the default apache installed in mac os, and the problem is solved.

Thank you very much for your help!